# Probability that a < b < c

Tags: probability

There are 50 numbered objects from 1 to 50. We extract 3 of these objects one after the other without reinsertion. Calculate the probability `P(a<b<c)`

Given 3 objects, they can be ordered in $3!$ different ways. Of all these ways only `1` satisfies `a<b<c` so the probability should be:

$P(a<b<c) = \frac{1}{3!} = \frac{1}{6}$

Is it solved in the right way?

Comment: Can you find the number of arrangements of three objects ? how many of these are in the right order ?

Answer (score 0):

[Completely basic probability point of view]

Given a set of $3$ numbers from the bag, what is the probability that the numbers are arranged the way you want? (Conditional)

Now use the theorem of total probability.

Same way, you can actually answer the question for drawing $k$ numbers out of the bag.